# Range Based For Loop on std::array

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdarray

I have an array of arrays and want to fill them up with some value.

This doesn't work:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 4> list;

for (auto item : list) {
    std::fill(item.begin(), item.end(), 65);
}
```

However, this does:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    std::fill(list[i].begin(), list[i].end(), 65);
}
```

What am I missing? Looking at the debugger, the first example does nothing on `list`. The type of `item` is `std::array<int, 5>`, as expected, so I'm not sure what went wrong.

Comment: `for (auto item : list) {` => `for (auto& item : list) {`

Comment: `auto` does not deduce references, so `item` is a copy of the element. Change to `auto& item`...

Comment: Understood. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first code snippet, the `item` variable will be a ***copy*** of each array in the loop; so, modifying that will not affect the 'originals'. In fact, as that `item` is never actually used, the whole loop may be "optimized away" by the compiler.

To fix this, make `item` a **reference** to the iterated array elements:

```cpp
for (auto& item : list) {
    //...
```

Answer (score 4):

Your first loop is roughly equivalent to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    auto item = list[i];
    std::fill(item.begin(), item.end(), 65);
}
```

Can you spot the problem? `item` is a copy of the array element. You are modifying the copy and not the element. Simple solution: Use a reference:

```
for (auto& item : list) {
```